# How to force retrieving app icon for apps downloaded from Google Play?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5, app-icons

On my Nexus 5 running Android KitKat 4.4.2, I noticed that from time to time, the apps I downloaded from Google Play would come with missing icon, so it defaults back to the green android robot icon:

[image: screenshot]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Two applications that I have found to produce the issue for me.

- [FLV Video Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.br.com.bitlabs.FLVPlayer)
- [Bayes Theorem](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thenewboston.katherine)

I have yet to figure out a proper solution to this, but I can't be the only person experiencing this issue, so I was wondering if any seasoned android users can help me resolve this issue.

I already tried to do a quick search on android stackexchange, and on google, but I did not come up with a solution that caters to stock android. I did find [something similar, but that appears to work only for for Kindle Fire](http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle/ref=cm_cd_et_md_pl?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdMsgID=Mx30JZT3WHTQHS0&cdMsgNo=13&cdPage=1&cdSort=oldest&cdThread=Tx3LX7YKQLVGHHF#Mx30JZT3WHTQHS0).

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you using the stock launcher or a custom one?

Comment: stock 4.4 kitkat launcher that comes with Nexus 5